# Why is my preferred CSS font not being used?

Tags: html, css

I want to use the font bmI0GxZww8t20K342Lco0g.woff2 for classd but it is not rendering in that font; what am I doing wrong?

```
<html> 
<head>
<style>
.classa {color:blue}
.classb {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:blue} 
.classc {
    font-family: TimesNewRoman, 'Times New Roman', Times, Baskerville, Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 15.3999996185303px;
    color:blue;
}
.classd @font-face {
    font-family: MyFont;
    src:
        url('bmI0GxZww8t20K342Lco0g.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('bmI0GxZww8t20K342Lco0g.woff') format('woff');
}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="csss.css">

</style>
</sead>
<h1 class="classa">Bro This Is Blue.</h1> 
<h1 class="classb">Bro This Is Blue.</h1> 
<h1 class="classc">Bro This Is Blue.</h1> 
<h1 class="classd">Bro.</h1> 
</html>
```

Comment: `line-height: 15.3999996185303px;` ???

Comment: Welcome to SO! Make sure as you move forward on this site to use a better title - it will help it get noticed better. Everyone posting on here has a problem that needs solved, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've asked for a step-by-step way to do this;

Copy/Paste the following code on your IDE (Notepad++/Dreamweaver), Save it as `jura.css` file.

```
   @font-face {
  font-family: 'Jura';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Jura Regular'), local('Jura-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/jura/v7/TTP6pkLK4ssO46rAsyf3PA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
```

The above font is available at http://conieco.com.mx/conieco_files/css

Open your html file and include the `jura.css` file as

```
 <link rel = "stylesheet" href= "jura.css" />
```

If the file `jura.css` is in another folder but in the same directory as your html file use this;

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href= "CSS/jura.css" />
```

If the `jura.css` file is in another folder that is in the previously stored path then;

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href= "../CSS/jura.css" />
```

Now you can use the font simply by;

```
.classd 
   {
    font-family: Jura;
   }
```

Note: the `<link/>` tag comes inside the `<head></head>` tag.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emkay992/nqk1mbfL/)

Comment: didnt work email me the full code (using my source code) at nateproductions@hotmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Put this to the style part:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Jura';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Jura Regular'), local('Jura-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/jura/v7/bmI0GxZww8t20K342Lco0g.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
```

And on .classd

```
font-family: "Jura", sans-serif;
```

Comment: Can you take my code and put that in there please? Because I'm a newbie in coding languages.

Comment: can i put it on a css file

Comment: if so how do i do that

Comment: sorry, I made mistakes, try this: 
`@font-face {
  font-family: Jura;
  src:  url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/jura/v7/bmI0GxZww8t20K342Lco0g.woff2) 
}
.classd  {
 font-family: Jura;
}`

Answer (score 1):

The @font-face declaration should be separate from the class rules. Basically, it adds your font to the list of available font-families that you can use to style elements. Once you've declared your font, then you can apply the font-family name you choose to .classd

```
@font-face {
    font-family: MyFont;
    src:
        url('bmI0GxZww8t20K342Lco0g.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('bmI0GxZww8t20K342Lco0g.woff') format('woff');
}

.classd {
    font-family: MyFont;
}
```

Depending on where your font files are stored, you may also have to edit the font url to make sure they're pointing to the correct location.